# Dropdown box on change event for multiple list box

Tags: javascript, html, perl, catalyst, template-toolkit

```
my ($self, $c) = @_;
$c->stash->{buildallinfo}=$c->model('DB::misc')->getTestInformation();
```

Buildall info dump is like :

```
Apple => type2=>[2,3]
     type4=>[2,1]

Mango => type6=>[2,3]
     type2=>[2,1]
```

How to render them in drop down box if drop down one chanes automatically drop down 2 should change?

= apple changes

it should automatically change another  it will have list of type2,4 thenn if thats selected it should show 2,3

how to achive this. I am not all getting right solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulation of the content within the drop-downs is a *client-side* function, and has to be handled by javascript. For Catalyst and TT, their work is done when the page is rendered - any manipulation beyond that is somebody else's problem.

This means that between your model, Catalyst and TT, arrangements have to be made for the data to be available to javascript. In other words, a line or two in Template Toolkit which ensures that whatever contents of your stash you need to access with javascript get converted to javascript variables.

Typically, I would do something along these lines, with some jQuery:

```
[% USE JSON.Escape %]

<script>
    var buildallinfo = [% buildallinfo.json %];
    // we now have a JS variable that matches the structure of the perl stash variable
    $('#select_1').change(function(){
         // adjust content of #select_2 using normal JS techniques
         // $.grep(buildallinfo, ...) or whatever
    });
</script>
```